# Get output from program into Ruby processing

Tags: ruby, linux, processing

I am using the [Ruby processing library](https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing).

I would like to pipe output from a program into my code. For example, `echo "hello" | rp5 run receiver.rb`.

In a normal program, I know I can accomplish this with

```
while $stdin.gets
  puts $_
  puts "Receiving!"
end
```

And I know that in processing, the program loops through the `draw` function continuously. So I tried this code, but it did not work, since it freezes on the line `puts $stdin.gets`. So I know it must be a problem with the pipes not matching up, so I'm going to try using named pipes so that there is no confusion.

```
def setup
    puts "setting up"
end

def draw
    puts "drawing"
    puts $stdin
    puts $stdin.gets
    puts "after gets"
    while $stdin.gets
        puts $_
        puts "Receiving!"
    end
    puts "done drawing"
end
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the name pipes worked. Check out [this example](http://www.pauldix.net/2009/07/using-named-pipes-in-ruby-for-interprocess-communication.html) to get you started and make sure you have the latest version of JRuby loaded.